# 25 WPF Calendars in one window, takes 5 seconds to open Window

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, calendar

I'm new to WPF, and trying to get an idea of just how much slower it might be.  I started a new WPF app, in Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4), and created this XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CalendarTest1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1000">
    <WrapPanel>
        <Calendar />
        <Calendar />
        <Calendar />
...repeats for a total of 25 calendar objects...
    </WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

When I run my application, in the IDE or not, it takes 5 seconds for the window to open.  Once open, it redraws quickly (as I resize it) and everything seems snappy.

My PC isn't the fastest: AMD Dual Core 2.3GHz, 2GB RAM, XP 32-bit OS, on-board video.

I can place 25 buttons, instead of Calendars, and that loads in less than 1 second.

I'm trying to create something like the little month calendars in the day view in the MS Outlook calendar, like this:

[image]

So I was thinking I could use a WrapPanel and add/remove Calendar controls as it resizes.  I might not need 25, but even with 9 or 12 it is slower than I would think (I have a legacy Win32 app that displays 18 calendars like this in less than 1 second).

**My questions are:**

Is the Calendar control slow because of a certain design -- either a bad design, or just not designed for this usage, or is it just slow because it is trying to display a lot of data/controls/info?

If I go to the trouble to create my own control, assuming I use a good design (general ideas welcome), can it be a lot faster, or is this just "typical" for WPF?

Is there something I can do to make the default Calendar control faster for this usage?

Comment: You measured for the first time or always it takes 5 second?

Comment: Try testing the exe, and not the visual studios debugger.

Comment: Always takes 5 seconds, even when I run the EXE directly, not from the IDE.  My PC isn't super fast.. but it handles VS 2010 fine, so I'd expect this little example to be very fast.

Comment: The Calendar control is a native control and rather a complex one. So yes, it is certainly not the fastest. Which make s your screen very much worst-case. Does it even resemble your final goal?

Comment: `trying to get an idea of just how much slower it might be` - Compared to what? to winforms? [**Please...**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA)

Comment: It is close to my final goal, yes.  I was able to remove the next/prev month buttons already, and also able to keep all of the calendars "in sync" (when one changes, they all change)... so it does work pretty much like Outlook.

Comment: @HighCore - slow compared to Outlook 2003 (I can load outlook.exe set to the calendar view, with 9 calendars visible, in less than 1 second).  Also compared to an app I wrote using Borland Builder C++, which uses the VCL library, which can display 18 months in less than 1 second.  A WPF EXE with 1 calendar loads in less than 1 second on my PC.  If I add 24 more calendars, then run the EXE, it takes 5 seconds to load (until window is open/visible).

Comment: I'm trying this with 25 calendars and I get avg load time of `1.55 secs` (I5 2500k processor @3.3 GHZ, 8 GB RAM @ 1033 MHZ. WPF 4.0 (F5 from Visual Studio, not EXE file)

Comment: OK, so possibly something about my PC is not ideal for WPF apps.  I suspect WPF is video card dependent, more so than WinForms (and other older platforms).  My target market is small business PCs though, so they will mostly be on-board video, and older.  Maybe WPF is not a good platform for me, based on my target... that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: @eselk I have an onboard video card too. and I also do apps for small businesses, and they run just fine. any .Net app will have a slower start up time compared to a native C++ app.

Comment: I tried with only 10 calendars and I get an average startup time of `58 secs` What OS are you running? I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise X64.

Comment: By the way, you're much better off building your own UserControl based on a `Virtualizing` ItemsControl rather than putting all these calendar controls together. They're not intended to be used that way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an answer per se, but adding this to `Window.Resources` reduced the load time 50% in my machine (which is now under 1 second for 25 calendars)

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" Margin="2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Calendar">
            <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

**Edit:**

This visual change does not affect the control's functionality. All the Calendar's Day items are still `Selectable`, and you can bind the `Calendar.SelectedDate` property.

There's just no visual indication that an item is selected, therefore clicking on the days seems to do nothing.

Just add this to your ControlTemplate:

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content" Margin="2"/>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- Set The FontWeight to "Bold" when Selected -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

You can play around with this `ControlTemplate` and its `Triggers` to add visual effects. Though keep in mind the more complex the template, the longer it will take to load.

Comment: +1 Good. Replaces the `CalendarButton` with a simple a `TextBlock`.

Comment: 50% here too, down to around 2 seconds.  The user needs to be able to click each day though.  I'm currently looking at ItemsControl as you suggested, and I think the "answer" really comes down to not using this control, for this usage, but that I will be able to create my own version, and it will be fast, so don't have to drop WPF all together.

Comment: @eselk the Day controls are still clickable. There's just no visual indication when a Day is Selected. See my edit

Comment: Oh, very nice.  Do you think I should continue optimizations of this sort (modifying template), or would I be better off creating a new Calendar control from scratch?

Comment: @eselk if the load time becomes acceptable to you, you can use that. Otherwise you'll have to start thinking about creating your custom stuff and add `Virtualization` capabilities. For example, Replacing the `WrapPanel` to a `VirtualizingStackPanel` will improve performance, but you'll see only 1 column of calendars

Comment: @eselk side comment: Once you learn WPF+MVVM, you will never want to look back again.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I've changed this to my accepted answer because I think this, plus all of your comments, gives me the most options.  I'm going to explore creating my own control, as a learning experience as well, but at least I have this to fall back on if that becomes too much work.  If I end up with any working code, I'll be sure to post it for future readers.

Comment: I agree MVVM is worth learning.  I've used Knockout JS in the web world.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you an idea of what a calendar *is* versus a button using Snoop. Yes, we do expect a lot of calendars to take a lot more rendering time. If you need to use a lot of them, I'd attempt to create your own that's simpler and/or virtualize them

Heres a button, 3 children...

[image]

And heres a Calendar, 522 children. Notice each of the `CalendarButtons` I didn't expand still have 9 children each

[image]
[image]

Comment: OK, this is what I was guessing, but didn't know how to be sure (haven't learned these tools/etc).  I assume it is possible to create a control like the Calendar control, that doesn't have nearly so many elements, and that would make it faster?  I guess the equivalent of using 1 owner-drawn window/control pre-WPF, instead of using a control for every day of the month.

Comment: Yes, without as many elements it would render faster. All those `CalendarDayButton`s are the clickable squares in the calendar control. All of those contain grids and rectangles. If you didn't need that feature you could save a bit of time by cutting them out, for example. Overall the calendar wasn't made simple because nearly everyone will only use one, while buttons are simple because usually you have quite a few of them. The nature of what a calendar is also makes it a more complex control.

Comment: I do need them all to be clickable (user can click any day to go to that date), but I imagine it is going to come down to a trade-off of speed vs ease of coding.  Instead of separate objects, will have one object and then have to calculate which day was clicked based on X,Y of mouse.  Feels like Win32 all over again.  I thought it might be different in WPF, since each of these objects isn't a window handle, and could maybe be less overhead.

Comment: @eselk what .Net version are you targetting? you should test this in a Windows 7 machine. XP is pretty much obsolete.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer.  While it doesn't give me any ideas as to where to start on creating my own, it does make it obvious that using the built-in control is not the way to go.  Also, in my opinion, shows that WPF isn't slow, but this control is just bloated.  So I feel that I should spend the time to create my own optimized control, and that it will work well, and I don't need to avoid WPF just because one control doesn't work well for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'll update this as I have time to finish up this new control, but so far I proved to myself that I can have a large number of controls in a window and still have it load quickly.  In this case, 1050 TextBlocks (7 columns * 6 rows * 25 instances of my user control), and my window loads in less than 1 second.

Here is my simple user control so far:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FastCalendar.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FastCalendar"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FastCalendar.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Margin="5">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl Width="180" Height="170" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Days, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=Row}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=Column}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Day}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

I placed 25 of those inside a WrapPanel, and it loads in less than 1 second.  I still need to add more controls and styles to my user control, but I'm thinking it will still be much faster than the built-in Calendar control (I hope).

p.s.-Even with 50 copies of my user control on the window, it loads in about 1 second.

Comment: As soon as I started setting basic properties on each cell/day, like HorizontalAlignment=Center, and a few other very basic things, it was getting too slow again for me.  So I'm redoing this using just a Canvas and overriding OnRender.  More work, but it is 100s to 1000s of times faster, so worth it to me (for a snappy interface that loads in 50ms vs 1000-2000ms, even on a slower PC).